# A way to monitor any UIView load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, code-injection

Actually this is a simple question with maybe not an answer for a central solution.

I would like a way to monitor in a central way every UIView start-finish loading to get metrics of the application.

I can see that viewWillLoad doesn't exist anyway in the UIViewController class and viewWillAppear is not something that it could serve the purpose.

Is this feasible in any way? I'm thinking of searching every UIView inherited class in the application and inject code somehow, but as I said I will need two methods.
Or maybe inject code to a protocol that already exists in the UIView class?

Any thoughts?

Regards.

Comment: do you only want to track the loading of root views of every view controller, or literally every view (therefore subviews of every view as well)?

Comment: The more the better, but I would like to hear what solution you have in mind.

Comment: If you're desperate to know when any UIViewController is loaded you could method swizzle the viewDidLoad method of UIViewController and then every single time that is called your code would be called first to do the analytics, then your code would need to call the original implementation. That's pretty brute force. I would take a more delicate, but labor intensive approach and subclass UIViewController to do the logging and have all of your view controllers inherit from the sub-classed UIViewController.

Comment: I want to measure the UIViews of all the UIViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with the loading of the root view of every view controller. You could [swizzle](http://cocoadev.com/MethodSwizzling) -loadView and -viewDidLoad of UIViewController. You could exchange those with methods that add start and end times to a table for each instance that calls them. Keep in mind though, that just the act of measuring it, you are going to slow down the loading.

---

If you want to track the loading of every view, you could swizzle -initWithFrame on UIView in the same way. In your version of the method you would start tracking before you call the real version and stop tracking once the real method has exited. However, if you have custom views that have their own initializers you will have to come up with a more complex version of that. **However I do not recommend doing this.** The time it takes to initialize a view is probably less time or at least very close to the amount of time it will take to track it making the timings worthless.

Comment: as long as custom views don't polymorphize their super methods, then it should work the same, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ya that is what I was trying to get across with the custom initializers. If additional initialization is happening in custom views outside of initWithFrame, then it won't be measured by simply swizzling the initWithFrameMethod.

Comment: So you mean I can swizzle the -initWithFrame of every UIView inherited class and if this class does not implement the -initWithFrame I will be able to measure it. Hmm, this solution seems interesting, I should create a sample application and test behavior.

Comment: You only have to swizzle -initWithFrame on the UIView class. But you will be missing initialization in custom subclasses if they override initWithFrame and do other initialization. It will still track the regular initWithFrame time but not any of the extra initialization. However, I recommend going the viewController route because I can't imagine all views being a useful statistic as it will include the time for individual subviews as well as views that contain many vies. Plus the time it takes to init a view is too close to the time it would take to track it.

Comment: True, in the -loadView method I can measure all the views loaded in the UIViewController at once. Maybe there is better since knowing the UIViewController that might take too much time to load you then know where to look for debugging purposes.